# How to read/write excel checkbox status in java

Tags: java, excel, radio-button

How can I  get the  radio value `(true or false)` from `excel2010` ?  in java,   thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to download the [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/) library. Then you can take help of the given below code to achieve what you want.

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("d:/file.xls"));

//Get the workbook instance for XLS file 
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

//Get first sheet from the workbook
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

//Iterate through each rows from first sheet
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rowIterator.next();

    //For each row, iterate through each columns
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
    while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {

        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

        switch(cell.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t\t");
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Have a look at this [link](http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Java-Beginners/29335-Retrieving-specific-data-from-excel.html) for more info.

Comment: it reads all except cells with checkbox form buttons.